# Find the generating set $\langle S\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S = \{4,22\}$, a subset of $U(\Bbb Z_{35})$. Find $\langle S\rangle$.

I have no idea where to start or what to do.

Comment: Do you know what $\langle S \rangle$ means?

Comment: For starters you should at least be able to find $\langle 4\rangle$, if you know what the angle bracket notation means.

Comment: <S> means the generators of S. But how would I find it? I am so lost. @rogerl

Comment: @Brian M. Scott

Comment: Well, what is the definition of a generator then?!

Comment: @user184332: No, $S$ is the set of generators of $\langle S\rangle$. $\langle S\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of $U(\Bbb Z_{35})$ containing $S$. So what things absolutely have to be in $\langle S\rangle$? Obviously $4$ and $22$, but also anything that you can get from them by applying the group operation of multiplication modulo $35$. For instance, $4\cdot4=16$ must be in $\langle S\rangle$. And then so must $4\cdot16=29$. And $4\cdot22=18$.

Comment: So would the answer to this problem be <S> = {4, 16, 18, 22, 29}?

Comment: @user184332: I’ve not worked it out in its entirety, but you’re definitely missing at least $4\cdot29=11$, $4\cdot11=9$, and $4\cdot9=1$.